# “Padding is invalid and cannot be removed” using AesManaged

Tags: windows-phone-8, encryption, aes

I am getting error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."
when trying to decrypt file contents in chunks(using buffer). I am able to decrypt whole file at once but not in blocks. I found many links regarding this problem and most of them suggested to set Padding of AesManaged object
like **aesManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.None**
But this property is not available in window phone application.
Below is method:

```
internal static byte[] DecryptBytes(byte[] cipherText, string password)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");

    byte[] decryptedBytes= new byte[cipherText.Length];

    using (var rijAlg = new AesManaged { KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128 })
    {
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Salt));
        rijAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(rijAlg.KeySize / 8);
        rijAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(rijAlg.BlockSize / 8);

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csDecrypt.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
            decryptedBytes = msDecrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

Please suggest issue in above code or any other workaround

Comment: `csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock()` should only be called on the [real] final block, not an arbitrary block. Also, what is the default `AesManaged::mode`? Is it a seekable mode? (And please don't tell me its ECB). And using the same {key/iv} pair that way is probably insecure, regardless of the cipher mode of operation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `aesManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.None` it will only hide the error, not solve it. You would get the error for incorrectly derived keys, incorrect ciphertext or - for smaller ciphertext - incorrect IV.

Print out the values of all the inputs in hexadecimals right before you perform the decrypt, then compare them with the ones obtained for encryption.